# android: Add a SharedPreference KEY dynamically

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a SharedPreferences file 'myprefs'. Then I use Editor to edit the **value** fields of the file.

```
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
//some codes to edit values
    editor.commit();
```

My question is , can I **add** one **KEY** field **through coding**?

Eg:- I have 2 keys name& age like

```
<Preference android:defaultValue="0" android:key="name"/>
<Preference android:defaultValue="0" android:key="age"/>
```

I have to add one more key 'email' **through java code**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will add the email address...

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("email", "email@email.com");
editor.commit();
```

See [**DOCS**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) for adding different data types to SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Simply call an `.put(..)` method on the editor and `commit()` afterwards. You need to pass a `String` as key and the corresponding value. The key can be anything. If there is no such value in the preferences, yet, then the framework will create it for you.

Answer (score 0):

To write to sharedPreference file:

```
 SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Nizam");
 editor.putInt("age", "39");
 editor.commit(); // Very important
```

To read from sharedPreference file:

```
SharedPreferences app_preferences1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

String name = app_preferences1.getString(name, "no name avail");//the first paramenter is the key for which you need the value.. the second one will be returned if the value for that key is not found
```

Answer (score 0):

what i do when i need to use sharedPrefrance is, create a pref class and put my pref code for complete application. i've added one of my pref class code. you can refer that.
in your case you can add key name by simply passing key Name.

like:

```
public void setEmailPref(String prfKey,String value){
       prefsEditor.putString( prfKey, value );
            prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

pref Class:

```
 public class GreetingCardData {
        public static final String SHARED_PREF_FILE     =   "greetingCardData";
        public static final String KEY_DO_NOT_SHOW      =   "doNotShow";
        public static final String KEY_CATEGORIES_JSON  =   "categoriesJson";   
        private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
        private Editor prefsEditor;

        public GreetingCardData(Context context) {
            this.sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILE, 0);
            this.prefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        }   

        public void setDoNotShowFlag ( boolean flag ){
            prefsEditor.putBoolean( KEY_DO_NOT_SHOW, flag );
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }

        public boolean getDoNotShowFlag(){
            return sharedPrefs.getBoolean( KEY_DO_NOT_SHOW, false );
        }

        public void setGreetingcardJson( String jsonString ){
            prefsEditor.putString( KEY_CATEGORIES_JSON, jsonString );
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }

        public String getGreetingcardJsonString(){
            return sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_CATEGORIES_JSON, "");
        }    
    }
```